# How to schedule a stored procedure in Oracle XE?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe

I'm using Oracle 10g XE and I'm trying to create a scheduled job for a stored procedure. I granted rights to `hr`

```
grant create job to hr ;
grant create external job to hr ;
```

then logged as `hr` and created a job

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name => 'THIS_IS_DA_NAME',
      job_type => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
      job_action => 'PROC_MYSTOREDPROC',
      start_date => sysdate + (5/(24*60)),
      repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY; interval=1',
      enabled => TRUE,
      comments => 'Runtime: Every day every minute');
end;
```

This succeeded. But the job does not show into `dba_scheduler_job_run_details` or `dba_scheduler_job_log`

```
select log_date, job_name, status, req_start_date, actual_start_date, run_duration
from   dba_scheduler_job_run_details

select log_date, job_name, status
from dba_scheduler_job_log
```

It is listed in this view/table

```
select *
from dba_scheduler_jobs
```

What is the problem here, why the stored procedure won't run? It runs fine using

```
exec PROC_MYSTOREDPROC
```

Also, running job instantly works just great

```
EXEC dbms_scheduler.run_job('hr.THIS_IS_DA_NAME');
```

Comment: Commit when? After the creating the job or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [`DBMS_SCHEDULER` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25788/d_sched.htm#CIHDJEEB):

> The `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` initialization parameter specifies the maximum number of processes that can be created for the execution of jobs. Beginning with Oracle Database 11g Release 2 (11.2), `JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES` applies to `DBMS_SCHEDULER` jobs. Setting this parameter to 0 disables `DBMS_SCHEDULER` jobs.

So make sure the [`JOB_QUEUE_PROCESSES`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams110.htm#REFRN10077) initialization parameter is set to a value above 1.

Also you need to commit to trigger the validation of your job request.

Once you have commited, the job will be scheduled in the `USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS` view:

```
SQL> select job_name, start_date from user_scheduler_jobs;

JOB_NAME        START_DATE
--------------- -----------------------------------
THIS_IS_DA_NAME 19-DEC-12 08.15.47.000000 AM -06:00
```

Of course, since you have asked for it to be scheduled five minutes in the future, there will be no rows in `USER_SCHEDULER_JOB_LOG` yet, but if you wait five minutes, you should see rows:

```
SQL> select job_name, log_date, status from user_scheduler_job_log 
      WHERE job_name = 'THIS_IS_DA_NAME';

JOB_NAME        LOG_DATE                            STATUS
--------------- ----------------------------------- -------------
THIS_IS_DA_NAME 19-DEC-12 08.15.47.009921 AM -06:00 SUCCEEDED
THIS_IS_DA_NAME 19-DEC-12 08.16.47.009534 AM -06:00 SUCCEEDED
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm using 10g XE, job_queue_process seems to have value 4.

Answer (score 0):

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable ('THIS_IS_DA_NAME');
```

and then try your code or this:

```
begin
  dbms_scheduler.create_job(
      job_name => 'THIS_IS_DA_NAME',
      job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
      job_action => 'BEGIN PROC_MYSTOREDPROC; END;',
      start_date => sysdate + (5/(24*60)),
      repeat_interval => 'FREQ=MINUTELY; interval=1',
      enabled => TRUE,
      comments => 'Runtime: Every day every minute');
end;
```

Comment: Should your first statement enable the job THIS_IS_DA_NAME instead of PROC_MYSTOREDPROC?

Comment: @jrara oh yes, sorry DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable ('THIS_IS_DA_NAME');

Comment: This create job statement works but the scheduler won't fire the procedure.